# pandas - extending the DataFrame by adding another levels

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's take an example DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(['a','b','c','d'],columns=['A'])
```

Now, what I want to do is to add two more columns (let's name them `B` and `C`) with numerical values that would be defined by some range - let's assume B in `range(0,3)` and C in `range(10,12)`.

The initial dataframe should be extended, so that for each value in column `A` there would be every possible combination of `B` and `C` values available - so the final dataframe should look like this:

```
    A  B  C
 0  a  0  10
 1  b  0  10
 2  c  0  10
 3  d  0  10
 4  a  1  10
 5  b  1  10
 6  c  1  10
 7  d  1  10
 8  a  2  10
 9  b  2  10
10  c  2  10
11  d  2  10
12  a  0  11
13  b  0  11
14  c  0  11
15  d  0  11
16  a  1  11
17  b  1  11
18  c  1  11
19  d  1  11
20  a  2  11
21  b  2  11
22  c  2  11
23  d  2  11
```

What will be the most optimal solution of achieving this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one called [cross product or cartesian product](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#brief-primer-on-merge-methods-relational-algebra). You can do it like this:

```
>>> dfA = pd.DataFrame(['a','b','c'],columns=['A'])
>>> dfB = pd.DataFrame(range(3),columns=['B'])
>>> dfA['key'] = 1
>>> dfB['key'] = 1
>>> pd.merge(dfB, dfA, on='key').ix[:, ('A','B')]
   A  B
0  a  0
1  b  0
2  c  0
3  a  1
4  b  1
5  c  1
6  a  2
7  b  2
8  c  2
```

Actually, it's strange that there's no possibility to pass `how='cross'` to merge or join methods. May be devs decided that it'll be not used very often.